# Laravel - Rendering a section of a view to PDF using domPDF

Tags: view, pdf-generation, laravel-6, dompdf

I have a Laravel 6 app and am using laravel-domPDF elsewhere in my app just fine. However, I want to create a PDF from a section of the view page. I have the HTML I need rendered-out stored in a variable, but the code to render out the HTML is PHP and I can't execute PHP from a button on the view page without a reload of the page, which loses the variable.

I have a controller just to render out the HTML, but can't find a way to pass that large HTML string to the controller from the view. I can't pass it via a route as it sends the HTML as a parameter attached to the URL and apart from looking terrible, it doesn't work.

How can I get a section of HTML in my view into the following PHP to render the PDF using a button on my view?

```
$pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
        $pdf->loadHTML($table_html_pdf);
        return $pdf->stream();
```

Comment: put the section of html to be rendered in a view component the view component will be added to the main page but send the variable data similar to passed in the view component when rendering it will solve your problem (I know its quite late but I try to answer dompdf question whenever I get time)

Comment: Thanks, but how can I do that when the code to use the DOMPDF package is PHP on the server? I currently have a complicated workaround, its a new controller that is mostly a copy of the page's controller that sends the HTML to the DOMPDF module. I was hoping for a way to capture the contents of the displayed page to PDF, especially with the input from the user on that page. I tried capturing the part of the page I wanted sent to PDF in a variable and pass that as a route parameter, but that didn't work as the long HTML string broke the parameter passing (as well as it being exposed in the URL).

Comment: instead catch the user inputs & send it the component which you will add in that view (which show the part in you want to make as pdf), & catch the import by creating a post request which gets triggered eg when user clicks the button Export as pdf, send the variable data to the component then  use dompdf

Comment: will try to share an example tomorrow